# List all sites in web application where user has member access

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, navigation

I want to list all the sites in a web application for the user where the user is either a member or admin (not visitor).

I definitely do not want to iterate through the sites. All the other options of using `SiteMap` or `Search` will return all the sites where user have some kind of access. I am currently looking at how membership web parts work in `MySite`.

How to proceed?

Comment: if you don't want iterate through all the sites you have to create a custom code.
Do you want that with Powershell, Server side code or client side code?

Comment: Since this will be used in a webpart it can either be a server or a client side code.

Comment: how many users do you have?

Comment: Well currently there are more than 30000 users added through Active Directory groups

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Core Results Search Web Part and hard code the following query to only bring back sites.  Then you can customize the XSLT to get it to look how you want.

```
contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web contentClass:sts_listitem_850
```

http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=90

Comment: Will this not return be all the sites where I have access? I want to the sites where the user is either member or owner, but not a visitor. In our current case the user will have visitor permissions on all most all the sites.